# how do i obtain images (url) online and place it in horizontal scroll view?

Tags: android, image, horizontalscrollview

I am currently developing an application, it consists of a cover flow page (from http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) . On each item, i have a "look inside" button and when I click that, I should be able to retrieve the url of that particular item and display the images (from online) in a horizontal scroll view (on the white spot below). Sorry for my bad english and I am new to android :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually achieve that easily by using iScroll 4.[visit here](http://cubiq.org/iscroll-4) for reference.

All you need is to implement it on a webview with javascript enable...

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);      
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
```

Another Implementation is called the SwipeView, also found on the same site.

Take a look at the site, lots of examples...might not be as pretty as cover flow, but i bet it will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you have a horizontal view, and you want to load some images from a server into your views, based on some user events (like clicking on button etc.)

To load the image, you can can use an HTTP connection to get the bitmap data, i.e extract the bitmap from the InputStream, and then pass it to an imageView. Check android bitmap and HttpUrlConnection docs for more details.

```
 URL imageUrl = new URL("http...."); //The url of the image             
 Bitmap bmp;
 ImageView imView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.xyz); 

 try{
        HttpURLConnection conn =  (HttpURLConnection)imageurl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        conn.connect();
        int length = conn.getContentLength();       
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();     
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        imView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
     } 

     catch(Exception e){}
```